# Optimizing the topological sorting

Tags: java, topological-sorting

I have implemented the topological sort.

Is there any suggestion for optimizing the solution?

Thanks.

```
package src;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Stack;

class Graph{
    int V;
    LinkedList[] edges;

    public Graph(int vertices){
        V =vertices;
        edges = new LinkedList[V];
        for(int i=0;i<V;i++){
            edges[i] = new LinkedList();
        }
    }

    // Time complexity O(V+E)
    public void topologicalSort() {

        Stack stacks = new Stack();

        boolean[] visited = new boolean[V];

        for(int i=0;i<V;i++) {

            if(!visited[i]){
                topologicalSortUtil(i,visited,stacks);
            }
        }

        while(!stacks.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println(stacks.pop());
        }

    }

    private void topologicalSortUtil(int i, boolean[] visited, Stack stacks) {

        stacks.push(i);

        visited[i] =true;

        Iterator<Integer> iterator = edges[i].listIterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){

            int item = iterator.next();
            if(!visited[item]){
                topologicalSortUtil(item,visited,stacks);
            }
            stacks.push(item);
        }

    }
}

public class TopologicalSorting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Graph graph = new Graph(8);

        graph.topologicalSort();

    }
}


package src;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Stack;

class Graph{
    int V;
    LinkedList[] edges;

    public Graph(int vertices){
        V =vertices;
        edges = new LinkedList[V];
        for(int i=0;i<V;i++){
            edges[i] = new LinkedList();
        }
    }

    // Time complexity O(V+E)
    public void topologicalSort() {

        Stack stacks = new Stack();

        boolean[] visited = new boolean[V];

        for(int i=0;i<V;i++) {

            if(!visited[i]){
                topologicalSortUtil(i,visited,stacks);
            }
        }

        while(!stacks.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println(stacks.pop());
        }

    }

    private void topologicalSortUtil(int i, boolean[] visited, Stack stacks) {

        stacks.push(i);

        visited[i] =true;

        Iterator<Integer> iterator = edges[i].listIterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){

            int item = iterator.next();
            if(!visited[item]){
                topologicalSortUtil(item,visited,stacks);
            }
            stacks.push(item);
        }

    }
}

public class TopologicalSorting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Graph graph = new Graph(8);

        graph.topologicalSort();

    }
}
```

Comment: Your source code is looking strange: you have shown two classes src.Graph as well as two src.TopologicalSorting (I didn't check whether they are identical or different), and I don't see how the graph is initialized - there just seems to be a constructor with empty lists.